# Excel median across multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Name: Number: CategoryA_1: CategoryA_2: CategoryA_3:
Pat     4       Car          Van             Bus
Mary    5       Van          Car
James   -       Bus
```

I want to be able to get the median 'number' for each category. So for example because 'Car' is in CategoryA_1 and CategoryA_2, I am trying to get the median of 'Number' 4 and 5.

I am calling this in another worksheet like so.

```
      Median
Car     4.5
Van     4.5
Bus     4
```

I have tried this (but am only getting 0, I can't figure out why it isn't working)

```
=MEDIAN(IF(OR('Sheet1'!c:c=a2, 'Sheet1'!d:d=a2, 'Sheet1'!e:e=a2),(IF('Sheet1'!b:b<>"-", 'Sheet1'!b:b))))
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That isn't at all clear, we need a better sample of data. "the median of 'Number' 4 and 5"  - what does this mean? Don't think OR works in array formulae.

Comment: Since there is a dash "-" in the :Number:", what will be the median for bus?

Comment: @SJR The median of 4 and 5 is 4.5. If the OR doesn't work, what does?

Comment: @p._phidot_ It will just be the median of the first row in that case. Ignore the dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "Name:" is located at A1 of sheet1, and the other worksheet is sheet2. In Sheet1 G1 put :

```
=Sheet2!A2
```

then in G2 :

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER($B2),$G$1<>"",C2<>"",C2=$G$1),$B2,"")
```

and drag to I4. Then in Sheet2, the formula should be :

```
=MEDIAN(Sheet1!G2:I4)
```

Idea n correction :
 In the original formula.. the `'Sheet1'!c:c=a2` part wont work, as you are comparing a range to a cell.

In the proposed solution, we added some error checking to ignore the dash using `ISNUMBER($B2)` , check/ignore blank entries using `$G$1<>"",C2<>""` and list the value only if the entered value in `Sheet!A2` is matched. then the median will work properly.

I'm not sure if this was mentioned in the help file (kindly have a check), but AFIAK, the median() function need  a list as its argument.. and the original if function seems to return a TRUE/FALSE value (instead of a list). Maybe that's why you get a 0.